# How to move a class into another package?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, eclipse

In Visual Studio I have a lot of classes and UserControls that I have to move into another namespace. In eclipse I can do it with updating all the references automatically. In Visual Studio I couldn't find a similar function. How is this possbile in Visual Studio?

Comment: If you mean moving the files themselves to different directory on the disk, nothing will be changed and it will compile just fine. Otherwise please elaborate on "move to other package" - what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Ok, I think i confused a package with a different namespace. For example i want to move a class from the namespace A to the namespace A.B. Then I have to updtae the using statements in other classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such functionality provided in Visual Studio. [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Refactoring/moveType.html) has such feature.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean moving between assemblies:

For *existing built* code you should add:

```
[assembly:TypeForwardedTo(typeof(SomeNamespace.TheControl))]
```

to the *original* assembly (that *no longer* contains `TheControl`). Then the CLR will sort everything out for you for existing built code *without* having to update the references.

However, for *building* code you will still need to update the references; I don't think vanilla VS has that built in.

Answer (score 1):

Rename is supported in VS for reference update, but not file or class movements

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It's really powerful refactoring tool fos VS. VS becomes even possible to use after installing it;) And it has tool for moving classes, methods, pulling up, pushing down, renaming and many more.